# if I sell to open a contract and the buyer buys to close a contract, will I get notification?

Tags: options

I'm reading/watching the basics of options trading.  I opened a demo account but until now, when I open an option contract, I have only gotten one of these three notifications\messages: working, filled, or expired.

More specifically, if I sell to open a contract and the buyer buys  to close a contract, will I get notification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if I sell to open a contract and the buyer buys [sic] to close a contract, will I get notification?

This doesn't make sense. The buyer doesn't BTC the contract. (Only you and other sellers can BTC the option). They can exercise it early, though. They call their broker and let them know that they want to exercise. Normally they won't do this, because they gain more from selling the contract than exercising it; the contract has time value (extrinsic). They'd be forfeiting this value, so they must have a good reason and strong desire to own stock in the case of an early exercise on a call.

You may have meant the following:

> if I sell to open a contract and the buyer b̶u̶y̶s̶  [sic] ***sells*** to close a contract, will I get notification?

In that case, the problem in your understanding is that you don't sell a contract to an individual. When you sell a contract, you are opening a short position, but no one in particular is the holder of that contract. In the event that a holder of a contract sells and closes out their position (STC), it has no impact on you. It just means that they've transferred the right to exercise the option to someone else. Your contract is still open.

Another question could be:

> if I sell to open a contract and the buyer b̶u̶y̶s̶  [sic] ***s̶e̶l̶l̶s̶*** t̶o̶ ̶c̶l̶o̶s̶e̶ ̶a̶ ̶c̶o̶n̶t̶r̶a̶c̶t̶  ***exercises their contract early***, will I get notification?

If they exercise the option early, you *may* be affected. Once again, you don't sell a contract directly to someone (although someone does typically purchase a contract at the same time that you sell one). If someone exercises early, their broker will give notice to the OCC, which then randomly assigns a market participant short of the identical option series (the same ticker, expiration date, and strike price). You may or may not be the one who's assigned by the OCC. If you're assigned, your broker will notify you, and your shares will be automagically sold to the person, early exerciser. This will rarely happen. Early exercise is not a particularly common practice.

Comment: Thank you very much. you uncloud my question, I understand it now

Answer (score 3):

When you execute any option trade, your broker will notify when the trade has occurred, hopefully in a timely fashion.  If you are selling to open, it is irrelevant whether the counter party is buying to open or buying to close.  After trade execution, for a STO, there are three possible events:

- You close the option position before expiration
- You are assigned before or at expiration
- The option expires worthless

Comment: I mean, aren't they supposed to tell me that. There are two scenarios; (1) if they told me; Let's say I exceute a weekly sell to open contract, and the losses I had if I closed it were greater than if I left it to expire, and I received a notification that the buyer had closed the contract, so I immediately issued a second contract because I have no potential assignments, as the contract is out of my custody

Comment: (2) if they didn't inform me, and I selled to open a weekly contract and then I excute another sell to open contract then the buyer of the first contract and the buyer of the second contract suddenly exersised both contracts, and I do not have enough money for them, then I will be in trouble

Comment: (Note): I talk about call options

Comment: The first paragraph of your question pretty much answers your subsequent questions. If your fill is a closing transaction, you can open another.  If the contract expires, you can open another.  If you have a working order, you have to wait to see if the order is completed or not.

Comment: Thank you very much